# Why do we use the article "the" with the Matterhorn (a mountain)?

Tags: articles, proper-nouns, toponyms

The rule is that we don't use an article before the name of an individual mountain, only with the name of a mountain range.

So why do we say "the Matterhorn" (a mountain in the Pennine Alps)?

Comment: Because (it's what we do).

Answer (score 6):

Like any rule in English, there are many exceptions.

- Generally we use "the" when the mountain is one of the earlier named Alpine German loanwords -- *the Matterhorn*, *the Jungfrau*, and so on. In these cases, the mountain's name tends to be self-descriptive (e.g. Matterhorn means "meadowed peak" in German, so "the Matterhorn" is talking about a specific one and not a general "meadowed peak"). But that's just an observation, not a rule.
- We can also use "the" when talking about a collection of mountains (either a full mountain range or just a group of mountains) -- *the Cascadia Range*, *the Blue Ridge Mountains*, or *the Himalayas*.
- Sometimes we omit the article altogether: *he managed to climb Everest last spring*.

Here's one rule that *is* pretty reliable: we don't use *Mount* and also an article. So you probably wouldn't see, e.g., "the Mount Matterhorn" or "the Mount Everest".

Comment: "We don't use *Mount* and also an article": Because "Mount" is a determiner and we cannot have two determiners?

Comment: Nice shout out to the Blue Ridge. *checks profile* Charlottesville. +1

Comment: @TRomano I think it's more convention than anything else. English does permit the use of multiple determiners in some limited constructions. Some regional American dialects are big on this. For example, "_Stay away from **the both of them**._" would be considered acceptable by many.

Comment: @John I'd say _both_ is more of a noun than a determiner there, exactly parallel to ‘the pair of them’.

Comment: Probably the use of the definite article reflects German usage. Names of mountain peaks are used with the article: das Matterhorn, der Watzmann, die Zugspitze.

Comment: @rogermue: How about *Lake Victoria*?